# Validate a login p_auth token against Liferay

Tags: javascript, rest, authentication, liferay, liferay-6

Is it possible to validate a given p_auth token - that Liferay generates for a logged in user - on the server to ensure it is indeed valid for a given user?

Basically I need a  way to call up a service on another server but I want this service to only be accessible if the user is logged in to Liferay and I thought if I could pass in the p_auth token that I would be able to validate that it is indeed valid and is for the right user.

How do I go about doing this? My research isn't yielding much at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not necessary to manually validate `p_auth`.

Use this code (by example):

```
PermissionChecker checker = PermissionCheckerFactoryUtil.create(user);

boolean isSigned = checker.isSignedIn();
```

Comment: Where does the `user` parameter come from? If I understood the question right, then this code should be executed on a non-Liferay server, but where does this server get the liferay user?

Comment: why non-Liferay server? My response is only for the right way to know is a user is logged (the code have to be executed within liferay). Maybe I dont understand well your needs...

Comment: Oh, now I understand, I had misunderstood the question

Comment: I don´t like this solution because it would allow anyone to execute the method as long as the specified user is logged in somehow. If User A calls the function with User Bs userId and User B is logged in on a different computer then User A could yo whatever he wants. p_auth is the better solution.

Comment: @Breiti I understand you point of view but consider the initial question right. It asks to have a secure service call and the permission checker is the mandatory way to do it. The p_auth validation comes to prevent the CSRF. Is it not possible to have p_auth only way.